# How to replace value of array key?

Tags: php, arrays, array-key

My array looks like below on `var_dump($user_jason)`:

```
'Gustav' => 
    array (size=9)
      'sum' => int 8
      'votes' => string '3' (length=1)
      'links' => null
      'comments' => string '2' (length=1)
      'topnews' => null
      'revisions' => string '3' (length=1)
      'translations' => null
      'skipped' => null
      'firstvotes' => null
  '' => 
    array (size=9)
      'sum' => int 6
      'votes' => null
      'links' => string '3' (length=1)
      'comments' => null
      'topnews' => string '3' (length=1)
      'revisions' => null
      'translations' => null
      'skipped' => null
      'firstvotes' => null
'Dennis' =>
```

Now where my key is empty I am trying to set that key as "anonymous" but I am not sure how to achieve this. I am trying like below :

```
foreach ($user_jason as $key => $value) {

      if(empty($key)){
         if(empty($key)){
          unset($user_jason['']);
          $key = "anonouymus";
          $user_jason[$key] = $value;
       }

      }
    }
```

But its still empty, please suggest how can I do this. Sorry for asking may this be easy but I am trying and not able to achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Empty key is in array but new key is added too. Unseting an element is done with `unset` function.

Comment: oh now I can see new key got added as "anonymous" so should i unset the key which is empty !, Thanks!

Comment: It worked like above now !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for the loop:

```
if(isset($user_jason[''])) {
    $user_jason['anonymous'] = $user_jason[''];
}
unset($user_jason['']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Code

```
$user_jason[$key] = $value;
```

doesn't mean that your empty key will be replaced with some value.

This code means that to your `$user_jason` array will be added new key `$key` and previous key (empty one) will still be in your array. You can unset it with `unset`:

```
unset($user_jason['']);
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining !